# SQL Developer How to export store procedures into separate files?

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2 and I have about 100 stored procedures/functions that I'd like to export them into separate individual files. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

1. Each file name should be the same as the stored procedure/function name.
2. The file content is just the content of the stored procedure/function, as if I open the stored procedure, copy and paste into a text file and save.

Any one knows how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's pretty much the same for all versions :  Tools -> Database Export, there you will be asked about many options like whether you want to have sql in one file or separate, types of object to export , etc...

Answer (score 8):

As [a1ex07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232403/a1ex07) stated in his comment. You can achieve that. Go *Tools -> Database Export -> Select the file where you want to create stored procedure/function and select the connection name -> Types to Export -> Specify Object -> Specify Data -> Finish*

[image]

[image]

Comment: any way to do this automatically every day?